# Como simular un Ctrl + Click en un link?

Tags: jquery, script

Quiero simular un Ctrl + Click en un link para que abra otra pestaña pero que en navegador no siga esa nueva pestaña, me explico? quiero quedarme en la misma pestaña. El ejemplo y problema:

```
<a class="btn btn-small" href="/en/upload-file" data-original-title=""><i class="icon-white icon-plus"></i> Add new</a>
```

Tengo este `Script` que no puedo adaptar

`var e = jQuery.Event("click");
e.ctrlKey = true;
$('#id').trigger(e);`

como pueden ver este `script` funciona con `#id` pero este `outerHTML` de ejemplo no tiene `#id`
Me pregunto si se puede hacer tomando como referencia el `class=` o directamente el `href=` como lo solucionarían ustedes?

Answer (score 2):

Buenas usa **target="_blank"** como atributo dentro del link a.

```
<a class="btn btn-small" href="/en/upload-file" target="_blank" data-original-title=""><i class="icon-white icon-plus"></i> Add new</a>
```

Si aun asi eso no es lo que buscas podrías buscarlo mediante el value de href en el caso de que no puedas añadir un Id o una Class nueva:

```
var e = jQuery.Event("click");
e.ctrlKey = true;
$('a[href="/en/upload-file"]').trigger(e);
```

o si quieres buscarlo mediante la clase :

```
var e = jQuery.Event("click");
e.ctrlKey = true;
$('a.btn-small').trigger(e);
```

Comment: buenas, la primera opción no me sirve, las otras dos no funcionan :( saludos

Answer (score 0):

a ver si esto te apaña,con lo que sea me cuentas:

```
            var j = jQuery.Event('keydown');
            j.ctrlKey = true;  
                if(j){
                    $('a.btn.btn-small').attr("target","_blanck");
                    $('a.btn.btn-small')[0].click();

                    }
```

Comment: hola, nop, este metodo agrega `_blanck` al enlace pero al hacer click el navegador abandona la pestaña activa y si uno vuelve a la pentaña donde está el `btn-small` e intenta nuevamente, el resultado es que se recarga la pentaña antes creada con el ´_blanck´
d todos modos gracias pero ya desistí de esto